# CSS text overflow ellipsis + width in % does not work

Tags: css

Text overflow works only if width is in pixel and does not accept percent.
I am having issue with firefox  dont know about other browsers.

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="item">
            <div class="name">Title Long Long Long Long Long 1</div>
            <div class="desc">Lore Lipsum Lore Lipsum Lore Lipsum Lore Lipsum Lore Lipsum Lore Lipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="name">Title Long Long Long Long Long 2 </div>
        <div class="desc">Lore Lipsum Lore Lipsum Lore Lipsum Lore Lipsum Lore Lipsum Lore Lipsum</div>
    </div>
</div>

.items {
   width:30%;
}
.item {
  display:table;
}
.item .name ,.item .desc  {
  display:table-cell;
        white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;    
    overflow: hidden;   
}
.item .name {
    width:20%;
}
.item .desc {
    width:80%;
}
```

fiddle link here: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bd3qxrpL/)

Inorder to make it work  I need to set maxwidth. This will impact the elements which are responsive

```
.item .desc {
    max-width: 105px;
    width: 80%;
 }
```

Comment: Do you use bootstrap? or similar framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Main problem here is that you are formatting your elements with `table(-*)` `display` values.

Tables have their own layout algorithm, and one basic component of that is, “make stuff as wide as needed to display the content”.

If you don’t want that, and want the widths that you specified to be honored no matter what instead, you need to use `table-layout:fixed`. On top of that you will need to specify `width:100%` for your `table` elements here, otherwise they will still flow out of the limited width container.

```css
.items {
   width:30%;
}
.item {
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed; /* added, so that width specifications will be honored */
  width:100%; /* needed so that these tables honor width of parent element */
}
.item .name ,.item .desc  {
  display:table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;    
  overflow: hidden;   
}
.item .name {
  width:20%;
}
.item .desc {
  width:80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
    <div class="item">
            <div class="name">Title Long Long Long Long Long 1</div>
            <div class="desc">Lore Lipsum Lore Lipsum Lore Lipsum Lore Lipsum Lore Lipsum Lore Lipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="name">Title Long Long Long Long Long 2 </div>
        <div class="desc">Lore Lipsum Lore Lipsum Lore Lipsum Lore Lipsum Lore Lipsum Lore Lipsum</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bd3qxrpL/2/

Answer (score 1):

The percentage widths aren't causing your problem here, it's actually the `display:table-cell` property. If you remove that, you can see it works as expected. If it's feasible, try using `inline-block` instead.